# ¿Cómo simular click a un item de un Menu Lateral en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un menú lateral con `NavigationView`, ¿Cómo se puede seleccionar un item especifico del menú lateral?

Es decir simular que el usuario ha hecho click sobre un elemento, he buscado, pero sin exito el `performClick` de las vistas comunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede usar directamente [onNavigationItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html#onNavigationItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) pasando el identificador del menuItem del `NavigationView` para simular su pulsación.

Por ejemplo si tenemos un elemento menú con nombre `nav_main`

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_main));
```

Dentro de:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    item.setChecked(true);
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_main:
        //realizar acción
    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedo asegurar se pueda realizar algo como un `performClick`, se podria simular seleccionando el elemento del menu con [setCheckedItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setCheckedItem(int)) y ejecutando el metodo del elemento:

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.mielemento);
execTarea();
```

Comment: Buenas, acabo de encontrar usando onNavigationItemSelected()

Comment: Ok pero ese es un listener, eso podria ayudar si es que no es necesario algo como un performClick , me parece que tambien se le manda el id del elemento (item).